# Converting to UTC time on my server does not work

Tags: c#, datetime

I am converting a user submited datetime to utc in my application:

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Parse(model.SessionEnd))`

I have also tried something like this

`combinedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(combinedDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

both work perfectly fine when im running the web app on my computer.  As soon as I upload it to the server and try it from there it just doesnt convert the time and ends up just returning the same datetime that i inputed.  I am sure my class library is being loaded correctly with the most recent version because Ive checked to see if my debug statements were being updated as well and they were.  Is this a server setting or something I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is the date and time on the server? What locale is it set to be in?

Comment: date and time on server is 7 hours ahead of my computer clock.  How can I check the locale ?  When I do `DateTime.UtcNow` on the server it gives the correct time. its only when converting the datetime

Comment: 7 hours ahead? Hmm - is the server by any chance already at GMT?

Comment: yes i believe it is, i looked it up online and the times match my server

Comment: ok nevermind, i think i know the issue.. i have to keep track of each users timezone in order for this to work properly cuz if they submit a datetime anywhere in the world as a string it'll all be the same if we don't know what timezone they are in

Answer (score 2):

The only sane approach is to make client code submit time/date time values with timezone. Generally converting to UTC on client is reasonable and supported by JavaScript too (if you still like timzone - use [getTimeZoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)). I'd recommend posting date time values formatted as ISO8601 in UTC (Z) timezone as well known sortable format without multiple meaning for the same string (2013-03-11T03:52Z).

Note that sometime you need time explicitly without timezone (like in wake me up at 9AM my time) - make sure to understand what is your use case.

Answer (score 1):

When your clients post the date times from client side as a string, you can do the following:

1.) You can convert their time to UTC on client-side (as in Alexei Levenov's answer)

2.) You can pass the client's time to the server and convert their time-zone at server-side

3.) You can convert their time to UTC on client-side and send their time-zone at server side

Depending on your needs you can choose any of these. The third is only useful if you want to use somehow their time-zone on server-side later.